# What's the generated query in sql for setFirstResult function in hibernate

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate

What’s the generated query in sql server for this query in hibernate:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(...);
c.setFirstResult(10);
c.setMaxResults(20);
```

Comment: Why don't you turn on sql tracing and see for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try executing it and watching your console for the query that's being created.

Since you're using multiple criteria, you'll need to experiment to see the exact effect that setFirstResult is having.